# FirewallD - forward-port and rate limit within one zone

Tags: firewalld

I am trying to create a zone in which I forward 3 ports to one other and at the same time need to apply a rate limit. The obvious would probably be rich rules, but they do not allow port-forward AND an action.

I have tried to combine forward-ports with a rich rule for the rate  limit. But in this case the rich rule seems not to be executed.

```
10-default-limit
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services:
  ports: 2022/tcp 3022/tcp 4022/tcp 8022/tcp
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
        port=2022:proto=tcp:toport=8022:toaddr=
        port=3022:proto=tcp:toport=8022:toaddr=
        port=4022:proto=tcp:toport=8022:toaddr=
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
        rule family="ipv4" port port="2022" protocol="tcp" log prefix="*** DEFAULT LIMITED - PORT 2022 MAPPED TO PORT 8022 *** " level="info" accept limit value="3/m"
        rule family="ipv4" port port="3022" protocol="tcp" log prefix="*** DEFAULT LIMITED - PORT 3022 MAPPED TO PORT 8022 *** " level="info" accept limit value="3/m"
        rule family="ipv4" port port="4022" protocol="tcp" log prefix="*** DEFAULT LIMITED - PORT 4022 MAPPED TO PORT 8022 *** " level="info" accept limit value="3/m"
        rule family="ipv4" port port="8022" protocol="tcp" log prefix="*** DEFAULT LIMITED - PORT 8022 *** " level="info" accept limit value="3/m"
```

It does the port-forward but does not apply the rate limit (and also no log entry is written)

I was also tempted to try with Zone Drifting, but as I have multiple zones chained it gets pretty unpredictable and also is not a recommended approach...

Is this combination possible at all? Any hint is much appreciated!